# Child theme TEMPLATEPATH issue

Tags: templates, child-theme

I have a template page that is supposed to load all blog posts(posts stream) and I am working in child theme. For some reason I get index.php returned from parent theme instead of modified one that I have in child theme directory.

code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/

// Which page of the blog are we on?
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
query_posts('cat=-0&paged='.$paged);


//load index to show blog
load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/index.php');

?>
```

Any ideas how to solve this, so it loads child theme index.php instead of parent?

Comment: Try `get_template_directory()` instead for `TEMPLATEPATH`. Return the absolute path to the directory of the current theme (without the trailing slash) - not the child.

Comment: This also returns parent directory, however STYLESHEETPATH returns the child themes path. Problem solved! Thanks for suggestion. :)

Comment: Right. I have understand your question that you like the parent theme. You should not work with the constant, maybe it is changed, use the function `get_stylesheet_directory()`.

Comment: get_stylesheet_directory() returns error for some reasone.

Comment: if that custom page template is attributed to the page set as 'posts page', it won't be used. really read https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page - also, there are other ways of changing what the index page shows; see https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: how are you distinguishing which index.php is called? are you using different codes within those files, or any marker html comments?

Comment: I've removed get_sidebar() in child and I can see it still uses sidebar as in parent. I've solved it, so no worries anymore. Thank you for the comments. :)

Comment: @MindaugasJačionis you should open a new thread for a new context. Also I add a solid answer there also help other readers, so I think.

Answer (score 4):

In your context you use the wrong constant. You must use the constant `STYLESHEETPATH` for the path to the active child theme. The constant `TEMPLATEPATH`get the path to the parent theme, that was referenced in the child theme.

But, a important hint. The constant is deprecated, see the [ticket #18298](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18298) for more information. That's is the point that you should use the function `get_stylesheet_directory()` to get the right path.

Additional also the hint, also the constant `TEMPLATEPATH` is deprecated and also here the hint to use the associated function `get_template_directory()`.